# How to remove the fuzzy innards from an artichoke?

Tags: artichokes

What is the best way to remove the fuzzy inner threads from on top of the artichoke heart, without losing too much delicious heart?

- Is it easiest to cut out the choke (the fuzzy stuff) before or after steaming the artichoke?
- Does anything work better than a spoon?
- Is there any way to remove the choke without cutting out pieces of heart?

Comment: What's wrong with just using a spoon?

Comment: Even fine dining restaurant in the world does it the same way - with a tea spoon.

Answer (score 6):

I believe, madam, that zanlok has the right of it-- a spoon.